# Malformed expression :"Error" when trying to retrieve value from hashmap

Tags: java, debugging, hashmap

I am trying to initialise the value of X to be the value of a hashmap.

Using the the IDE debugger , I can clearly see that the key-value of the hashmap has been initialised

[image]

However when i hover over the value of "secondcol" , i get the following

[image]

I don't understand how it is that the hashmap shows that the value has been initialised however the "secondcol" shows a malformed expression.

Moving on to the next step will cause a Null PointerException Error

What is happening and how do i resolve this issue ??

Comment: Collections must use boxed equivalents of primatives. In your case, the keys of the hash map are of type Integer. The for loop uses primitive ints. Have you tried explicitly boxing i?

Comment: What do you mean by "boxing i"

Comment: I posted something in the answer section to demonstrate boxing.

Answer (score 0):

From the debugger it looks like the code should be

`=CurrentPeerNode.ftable.table.get(i).value.secondcol`

and

`=CurrentPeerNode.ftable.table.get(i).value.thirdcol`.

(You were missing the .value)